# Upward continued fractions

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

Has anybody seen "upward continued fractions", such as
$$
\frac{1+\large{\frac{1+\large{\frac{1+...}{a_2}}}{a_1}}}{a_0} \quad?
$$

These can be formed, for any real number $x$ with $0<x\le 1$, by defining $x_0:=x$ and inductively 
$$
a_n:=\lfloor{x_n}\rfloor+1\qquad\text{and}\qquad x_{n+1}:=a_nx_n-1.
$$
It is easy to check that $1\le a_1\le a_2\le a_3\le\dots$, and that the sequence of $a_i$'s is eventually constant if and only if $x$ is rational.  This procedure yields expressions like the one displayed above, since
$$
x = \frac{1+x_1}{a_0}=\frac{1+\large{\frac{1+x_2}{a_1}}}{a_0}
=\frac{1+\large{\frac{1+\Large{\frac{1+x_3}{a_2}}}{a_1}}}{a_0} = \cdots
$$
I looked for these in google, wikipedia, and standard texts like Perron's, but couldn't find them.  Have they been studied?  I ask because a high school student invented these before my eyes today, and I'd like to tell him what he's rediscovered (assuming that in fact these have been studied before).

Comment: Yes. They exist, but are not widely used.

Comment: @Lucian: could you give me a reference or keyword?

Comment: I think one big reason these are rarer is because the fact that you can 'distribute' the division means that they can be equivalently written as $\frac1{a_0}+\frac1{a_0a_1}+\frac1{a_0a_1a_2}+\cdots$.  I'd swear I've seen some discussion of the latter, particularly in conjunction with the series for the exponential (note that setting $a_i=i+1$ gives you a 'continued fraction' for $e$), but I'll have to go digging for refs.

Comment: Ahh!  Here it is.  This is apparently known as the _Engel expansion_ : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engel_expansion

Comment: Also, kudos to your student for hitting on the idea - that's a great bit of thinking!

Comment: @Steven: thanks for the answer, and the kudos -- what the student did was even more impressive than it sounds, since we gave him zero background information and simply asked him to prove on day 1 that for any positive real numbers $a,b$ there exist nonzero integers $p,q$ with $|qa-p|<b$.  He invented these Engel expansions on the spot, and used them to prove what we asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding my comments into an answer: by distributing the divisions by $a_0$, $a_1$, $\ldots$ successively you can rewrite such an upward continued fraction in the equivalent form $\frac1{a_0}+\frac1{a_0a_1}+\frac1{a_0a_1a_2}+\cdots$.  This is known as the *[Engel expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engel_expansion)* of the number, and their coefficients have some interesting limiting properties (in particular, for almost all real numbers the coefficients grow exponentially); the Wikipedia article on them should offer up several good pointers for more information.

Comment: The Engel expansion for $e$ is particularly nice.

Answer (score 1):

Five years ago or so I worked on some "tree-type" continued fractions...
$$
T =
1+\frac{\displaystyle
 1+\frac{\displaystyle
   1+\frac{\displaystyle
     1+\frac{1+\cdots\;}{2+\cdots\;}
   }{\displaystyle
     2+\frac{2+\cdots\;}{4+\cdots\;}
   }
 }{\displaystyle
   2+\frac{\displaystyle
     2+\frac{2+\cdots\;}{4+\cdots\;}
   }{\displaystyle
     4+\frac{4+\cdots\;}{8+\cdots\;}
   }
 }
}{\displaystyle
 2+\frac{\displaystyle
   2+\frac{\displaystyle
    2+\frac{2+\cdots\;}{4+\cdots\;}
   }{\displaystyle
    4+\frac{4+\cdots\;}{8+\cdots\;}
   }
 }{\displaystyle
   4+\frac{\displaystyle
    4+\frac{4+\cdots\;}{8+\cdots\;}
   }{\displaystyle
    8+\frac{8+\cdots\;}{16+\cdots\;}
   }
 }
} \;.
$$

But it never went very far.  I did submit one of these as a problem...
*Math. Mag.* **79** (2006) p.151

Comment: I've seen this in a quite long treatize with the name "the fifth operation" ("la quince operationi" or the like of someone fellow from Spain) and he even has made a book out of it. Don't have the link at the moment, perhaps this can be found using google or the webarchive.

Comment: Here is a better reference, but not yet a link. Try webarchive with it: The Fifth Operation / La Quinta Operacion by Domingo Gómez Morín (2002-01-22) I don't know exactly why, but in the newsgroup sci.math he was handled as a slight crackpot because of the consequences he wanted to derive from his idea of such fractal continued fractions...

Comment: Ah, here it is: https://web.archive.org/web/20081221211317/http://mipagina.cantv.net/arithmetic/gencontfrac.htm

Comment: I had a recent question about this kind of fractions. They can be reworked into the generalized continued fraction form

Comment: The author of the book mentioned in my earlier comment added a comment with the current link, but in an answer-box(now deleted because it is no answer to the question). Here is his *comment* : *any thanks to Gottfried Helms for pointing out my work.

The updated link that fully answer this question and other
comments on this thread is:

https://domingogomezmorin.wordpress.com/

The aforementioned bifurcated fractions are fully explained
there as well as some other related stuff.*

Comment: @GottfriedHelms tommy owns the book by him and I borrowed it once , but there is no direct reference for such fractions. the fractal fractions he uses have a different pattern like some parts staying constant like 3 in 1 + (2 + 4/3..)/(3 + (2 + 4/3) and similar. It might be linked though but for now I am skeptical. I will inform him, see what he says.

Comment: have you tried with fibonacci numbers , squares or cubes ?

Comment: or multinomial coefficients ? Like a pascal triangle on its side with fractions ?

Comment: Hi @mick - thanks for notification. Usually I'm quickly curious on such things, but because of the belittleing by "crackpot" in sci.math I (nowadays I say:"unfortunately") didn't step in deeply. So I cannot say much more today. I'll be interested if you find interesting things in it...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms are you being insulted on sci.math ? or someone else ? Im not sure what you are saying. Link ? My english not perfect sorry

Comment: @mick - :-) No, thank you, not me has been belittled but the author of the book. I just didn't want to step in and be involved in such a soap opera (I basically was curious for his ideas instead)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms ah ok yeah. I read that in the past. Sad story. Im aware the book is controversial. But lets leave that for a chat.

Answer (score 0):

You can find plenty on information on those special continued fractions at
the following link (American Mathematical Monthly):

https://www.facebook.com/AmerMathMonthly/photos/a.250425975006394.53155.241224542593204/1055084257873891/?type=3&theater

Also at:
https://youtu.be/mjSHenvXsEs

Comment: The actual links to that work are: