# Simplifying a complicated continued fraction expression.

Tags: numerical-methods, radicals, closed-form, continued-fractions, bifurcation

This probably relates to continued fractions or numerical methods but I do not see how.

There is probably some kind of induction or telescoping.

$$\sqrt 3 = 1+\dfrac{2+\dfrac{3+\dfrac{4+\cdots}{5+\cdots}}{4+\dfrac{5+\cdots}{6+\cdots}}} {3+\dfrac{4+\dfrac{5+\cdots}{6+\cdots}}{5+\dfrac{6+\cdots}{7+\cdots}}} $$

(The pattern is +1 when going up and +2 when going down).

I tried to transform it into a simple continued fraction but failed.

How to prove this ?

It reminds me of this one

[why is $ 2 = \frac{5}{1+\frac{8}{4+\frac{11}{7 + \frac{14}{10 + \dots}}} } $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4435750/why-is-2-frac51-frac84-frac117-frac1410-dots)

***edit***

even more related seems this one :

[Is this formula for $\frac{e^2-3}{e^2+1}$ known? How to prove it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2134031/is-this-formula-for-frace2-3e21-known-how-to-prove-it)

***edit 2***

Some have claimed the value is in fact larger than $\sqrt 3$ ( I need to check myself )

but it seems that maybe the correct value is this one :

https://oeis.org/A048836

??

***edit 3***

I added another conjectured value in the comments but neither of them seems to be correct.

The value is a mystery at the moment.

My apologies for the wrongly assumed closed forms.

---

Comment: I think the two linked ones can help solve the problem ...

Comment: For this tree-fraction  I get numerically the value $1.728755$, so it is not $\sqrt{3}$ .

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1506472/442

Comment: @GEdgar I made some comments there.

Comment: @GEdgar see the edit : https://oeis.org/A048836 ??

Comment: or maybe $1/7*(17^{1/2}+11^{1/2})*7^{1/4}$

Comment: No, more accurately the fraction evaluates to $1.72875521836$, whereas that formula evaluates to $1.72875587428$.

Comment: @robjohn I posted 2 formula's. So is the fraction not equal to neither of them or do you mean not equal to one of them ?

Comment: The one just preceding my comment: $1/7*(17^{1/2}+11^{1/2})*7^{1/4}$. The other can be read directly as $1.72875760530$.

Comment: @robjohn do you believe the number is algebraic ? Considering the links, it seems very similar.

Comment: I have no idea if the number is algebraic. I don't see any reason that it should be, but it *could* be.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, more of an extended comment, not really part of the main question , just related observation :

Consider

$$f(x) = x+1+\dfrac{x+2+\dfrac{x+3+\dfrac{x+4+\cdots}{x+5+\cdots}}{x+4+\dfrac{x+5+\cdots}{x+6+\cdots}}} {x+3+\dfrac{x+4+\dfrac{x+5+\cdots}{x+6+\cdots}}{x+5+\dfrac{x+6+\cdots}{x+7+\cdots}}} $$

This function is remarkable.

At first you would think it has poles for some negative integers, then you notice that idea came from truncating and it might not actually have poles there.

Also

$$f(x) = x + 1 + \frac{f(x+1)}{f(x+2)}$$

This implies it has poles when $f(x+2)=0$ and if that is the case ,
we have $f(x) = x+1 + \infty = \infty$.
But that implies that $f(x-2) = (x-2) + 1 = x-1$.
And an infinite amount of identities follow.
Notice $f(x-2) = (x-2) + 1 = x-1$ implies that $x$ is not real and thus neither is the pole of $f(x+2)$ !

I wonder where the fixpoint of $f(z)$ are.

And what the taylor series for $f(z)$ looks like.

But perhaps a more fun idea is what happens when $x$ goes to $\infty$ ?

A first naive method is

$$f(x) - x =  1 + \frac{f(x+1)}{f(x+2)}$$

And then assume

$$\ lim f(x) - x - 1 = L $$

IF correct , this implies in the limit :

$$ 1 + L = 1 + \frac{x + 2 + f(x+2)/f(x+3)}{x+3 + f(x+3)/f(x+4)} = 2$$

by assuming the ratio of f(x+2)/f(x+3) converges at the same rate as f(x+3)/f(x+4).

This implies the ratio converges to $1$.

So we get the stronger

$$\ lim f(x) - x = 2 $$

It even seems reasonable to assume

$$\ lim f(x + k i) - (x + ki) = 2 $$

for real $k << x$ even if $k$ is also going to infinity.

This implies $f(x)$ is not a polynomial.

Maybe more a shape like $Erf(z)$ for $Re(z)>1$ based on the above.

Maybe $f(x)$ is close to $2 + a \cdot Erf(z) + b \cdot Erf(z)^2$ for $Re(z)>1$.

The functional equation for $f(x)$ reminds me of this :

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/348568/about-a-n-fraca-n-1a-n-1-ca-n-2

[$ a_n = \frac{a_{n-1}(a_{n-1} + 1)}{a_{n-2}}.$ and $ T = 3.73205080..$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3396793/a-n-fraca-n-1a-n-1-1a-n-2-and-t-3-73205080)

or maybe fibonacci or somos sequences.
It looks a bit similar.

Just some ideas.